# Separar una fecha (dd/mm/yyyy) en diferentes options

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html5

¿Como hago para separar la fecha actual en tres options.

Por ejemplo:

[image: Ejemplo registro de facebook fecha]

y luego volver a juntarlos?

Tengo esto funcionando pero me han pedido que lo cambie y no encuentro nada sobre hacer lo que pregunte.

```
<tr>
   <th >Fecha de Emisión</th>
   <td>
       <input class="form-control" style="width: 30%;"  type="date" ng-model="datosNuevoCarnet.NuevoCarnet.Emision" />
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Fecha de Vencimiento</th>
    <td>
         <input class="form-control" style="width: 30%;" type="date" ng-model="datosNuevoCarnet.NuevoCarnet.Vencimiento" />
     </td>
</tr>

$scope.datosNuevoCarnet.NuevoCarnet.Emision = new Date();
$scope.datosNuevoCarnet.NuevoCarnet.Vencimiento = new Date(newDate().setYear($scope.datosNuevoCarnet.NuevoCarnet.Emision.getFullYear() + 5));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una opción sería tener un campo escondido (*hidden*) y añadir un controlador del evento `change` a las tres listas desplegables, que actualizará el campo escondido con el nuevo valor. Luego en el servidor, en lugar de leer las listas desplegables, lo que haces es leer ese campo escondido.

En realidad sería `type="hidden"`, pero para este ejemplo voy a poner `type="text"` para que sea visible, no olvides cambiarle el tipo:

```js
var aux = document.querySelectorAll(".crea-fecha");

for(var x = 0; x < aux.length; x++) {
  aux[x].addEventListener("change", function() {
    document.getElementById("fecha").value = document.getElementById("year").value + "-" +
                                             document.getElementById("month").value + "-" +
                                             document.getElementById("day").value;
  });
};
```

```html
<select id="day" class="crea-fecha">
  <option value="01">1</option>
  <option value="02">2</option>
  <option value="03">3</option>
  <option value="04">4</option>
  <option value="05">5</option>
  <option value="06">6</option>
  <option value="07">7</option>
  <option value="08">8</option>
</select>
<select id="month" class="crea-fecha">
  <option value="01">Enero</option>
  <option value="02">Febrero</option>
  <option value="03">Marzo</option>
  <option value="04">Abril</option>
  <option value="05">Mayo</option>
  <option value="06">Junio</option>
  <option value="07">Julio</option>
  <option value="08">Agosto</option>
</select>
<select id="year" class="crea-fecha">
  <option value="2016">2016</option>
  <option value="2017">2017</option>
  <option value="2018">2018</option>
  <option value="2019">2019</option>
  <option value="2020">2020</option>
  <option value="2021">2021</option>
  <option value="2022">2022</option>
  <option value="2023">2023</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="fecha" value="2016-01-01" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Buen dia, has probado con jquery?
http://vitalets.github.io/combodate/

```html
<input type="text" id="datetime12" data-format="DD-MM-YYYY h:mm a" data-template="DD / MM / YYYY     hh : mm a" name="datetime" value="21-12-2012 8:30 pm">
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#datetime12').combodate();  
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar jQuery

```
<script src="http://vitalets.github.io/combodate/combodate.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="fecha" data-format="DD-MM-YYYY" data-template="D MMM YYYY" />

<script >
 $(function(){
   $('#fecha').combodate({
      value: new Date(),
      maxYear: moment().format('YYYY')  
  });    
 });
</script>
```